# Does an ASP.NET web application require a physical directory matching its IIS virtual path?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

This is IIS7.5 and .NET 4.0.  Here's the scenario:

1. A website `localhost` is setup at path `C:\wwwroot\`; it contains only a `Default.html` file.
2. A C# web application `MyWebApp` is stored at `C:\MyWebApp\` (outside the web root)
3. `MyWebApp` is registered as a web application on `localhost` at `/foo/bar/MyWebApp`
4. `MyWebApp` has a web.config with connection strings, etc. in its root

When I visit `http://localhost/foo/bar/MyWebApp`, it throws an exception about a missing connection string.  Turns out that `ConfigurationManager` does not contain *any* of the configuration from `MyWebApp`'s web.config.  The server **does parse the web.config**, because if I add malformed XML it throws an exception.  The config data just is not merged in.

What I found was that `localhost` must contain a physical directory at `C:\wwwroot\foo\bar\MyWebApp` for the `C:\MyWebApp\Web.config` to be included!

I have been unable to find anywhere this behavior is documented.  Is it required that a physical path exists for a web application registered at a virtual path?

Comment: No, you should definitely be able to map a virtual directory to a different path other than the physical path.  That's the entire point of a virtual directory.

Comment: I was able to successfully map a directory in IIS to http://localhost/MyWebApp to c:\PathOutsideWebRoot.  I have not tried multiple levels like you specified.  Are foo and bar physical folders within your web root, or are they virtual as well?

Comment: Mike, it only seems to be multiple levels.  The foo and bar were not physical folders.  Creating them makes the web.config visible though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup.  When I try to setup a web application within a website, it does not let me create a multi-level alias like /foo/bar/MyWebApp

Comment: Steve, very interesting!  The Web Application is being created by Visual Studio 2010's publish feature (project properties, Web tab).  The property page happily takes a multi-level alias and creates it.  I'm not sure how I've never run into this before.